# Google App Engine URL Fetch Doesn't Work on Production

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I am using google app engine's urlfetch feature to remotely log into another web service.  Everything works fine on development, but when I move to production the login procedure fails.  Do you have any suggestions on how to debug production URL fetch?

I am using cookies and other headers in my URL fetch (I manually set up the cookies within the header). One of the cookies is a session cookie.

There is no error or exception. On production, posting a login to the URL command returns the session cookies but when you request a page using the session cookies, they are ignored and you are prompted for login information again. On development once you get the session cookies you can access the internal pages just fine.  I thought the problem was related to saving the cookies, but they look correct as the requests are nearly identical.

This is how I call it:

```
fetchresp = urlfetch.fetch(url=req.get_full_url(),
    payload=req.get_data(),
    method=method,
    headers=all_headers,
    allow_truncated=False,
    follow_redirects=False,
    deadline=10
    )
```

Here are some guesses as to the problem:

- The distributed nature of google's url fetch implementation is messing things up.
- On production, headers are sent in a different order than in development, perhaps confusing the server.
- Some of google's servers are blacklisted by the target server.

Here are some hypothesis that I've ruled out:

- Google caching is too aggressive. But I still get the problem after turning off cache by  using the header Cache-Control: no-store.
- Google's urlfetch is too fast for the target server. But I still get the problem after inserting delays between calls.
- Google appends some data to the User-Agent header. But I have added that header to development and I don't get the problem.

What other differences are there between the production URL fetch and the development URL fetch? Do you have any ideas for debugging this?

**UPDATE 2**

(First update was incorporated above)
I don't know if it was something I did (maybe adding delays or disabling caches mentioned above) but now the production environment works about 50% of the time. This definitely looks like a race condition. Unfortunately, I have no idea if the problem is in my code, google's code, or the target server's code.

Comment: You haven't provided any details other than "doesn't work" - what happens when you run this code? Have you tried pointing it at a site you control so you can log the incoming request?

Comment: Good idea. I tried pointing it at a control site and I've diffed the two request objects. They are nearly identical. Maybe the google IPs are blacklisted, I'm not sure.

Comment: You still haven't explained what "doesn't work" means in this context.

Comment: I explained that the login procedure failed in my original post. I've edited it to add more detail.

Comment: Why on earth are you making requests to yourself, using cookies no less?

Comment: Jeez. I'm using it as debugging tactic. I want to figure out why urlfetch is broken in the production environment but I don't own the target server. Therefore, everytime I make a urlfetch call to the target server, I make an identical call to myself (i.e. a control site) so I can see exactly what urlfetch is doing under the hood. Get it?

Comment: I'm still working on my ability to read minds. If you control the target site, you should be able to tell us what's different. Are the cookies valid as received? If so, you need to debug your own code to determine why you think it's not logged in.

Comment: I found a number of differences such as caching, the user-agent, header order and timing that I discuss above (no mind-reading necessary).  However, there is one major difference left: on production, requests come from a whole bunch of IPs but on development, requests only come from one IP. On a properly functioning system, this shouldn't make a difference. I suppose there's something wrong with the target server.  That doesn't really help my situation though.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the key differences between dev and prod are the originating IP, and how some of the request headers are handled. See [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Request_Headers) for a list of restricted headers. I don't know if this is documented, but in prod, your app ID is appended to the end of your user agent. I had an issue once where requests in prod only were getting detected as a search engine spider because my app ID contained the string "bot".

You mentioned that you're setting up cookies manually, including the session cookie. Does this mean that you established a session in Dev, and then you're trying to re-use it in prod? Is it possible that the remote server is logging the source IP that establishes a session, and requiring that subsequent requests come from the same IP?

You said that it doesn't work, but you don't get an exception. What exactly does this mean? You get an HTTP 200 and an empty response body? Another HTTP status? Your best bet may be to contact the owners of the remote service and see if they can tell you more specifically what was wrong with your request. Anything else is just speculation.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. (1) I see the same thing you mentioned, the app id is being appended to the user-agent. I wonder if that's causing the problem, I'm not sure. (2) I'm not trying to reuse sessions across dev and prod. (3) I'm going to try the same thing on a pure django installation and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Check your server's logs to see if GAE is chopping any headers off.  I've noticed that GAE (thought I think I've seen it on the dev server) will chop off headers it doesn't like.

Depending on the web service you're calling, it might also be less ok with GAE calling it than your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this issue while making a webapp with an analogous issue- when looking at [urlfetch's documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction), it turns out that the maximum timeout for a fetch call is 60 seconds, but it defaults to 5 seconds.

5 seconds on my local machine was long enough to request URLs on my local machine, but on GAE it was only consistently completing its task in 5 seconds about 20% of the time.

I included the parameter `deadline=60` and it has been working fine since.

Hope this helps others!